# Ubuntu Stuck In Login Loop After Reinstall

Tags: login, lightdm, intel, login-screen, reinstall

I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 LTS due to getting stuck at the splash-screen for an unexplainable reason. However, now I get caught in a login loop instead. My hardware is a Dell XPS-13 9350. I appear to be having a very similar problem to these:

[Caught in loop when trying to login after upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612973/caught-in-loop-when-trying-to-login-after-upgrade-from-14-10-to-15-04)

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

None of the suggested solutions in the above threads are working. In fact it appears the original posters never found their answer.

Replacing lightdm with gdm means I get a blank purple screen instead. Reinstalling the intel drivers has no effect. I don't have any nvidia drivers causing issues.

The contents of xsession-errors:

[image]

Further potentially useful information: after hitting enter on the login screen I also get "System Program Problem Detected" dialog box. The screen also briefly flashes black with this line:

[image]

That partition is the main Ubuntu partition, but I also have partitions for boot and swap. When I installed gdm and tried to access TTY it said it was on hold while boot processes finish.

Comment: For anyone in the future who might read this... I seem to have diagnosed and fixed the problem. After the reinstall many of the files in my home directory had owners `1001:1001`? I used the command `sudo chown -R from=1001:1001 user:user ~` and this got me in.